# Change JSON key names (to all capitalized) recursively?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to change all JSON key names to capital letter ?

eg:

```
{"name":"john","Age":"21","sex":"male","place":{"state":"ca"}}
```

and need to be converted as

```
{"NAME":"john","AGE":"21","SEX":"male","PLACE":{"STATE":"ca"}}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your comment,

> eg like these will fail for the inner keys
>   {"name":"john","Age":"21","sex":"male","place":{"state":"ca"}}

You may need to use recursion for such cases. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/XBWFC/3/)

```
var output = allKeysToUpperCase(obj);

function allKeysToUpperCase(obj) {
    var output = {};
    for (i in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj[i]) === '[object Object]') {
            output[i.toUpperCase()] = allKeysToUpperCase(obj[i]);
        } else {
            output[i.toUpperCase()] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

A simple loop should do the trick,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/XBWFC/)

```
var output = {};
for (i in obj) {
   output[i.toUpperCase()] = obj[i];
}
```

Comment: Do note that the keys in lowercase are still present

Comment: @Elvis Nope, I am creating a new object `output`

Comment: eg like these will fail for the inner keys `{"name":"john","Age":"21","sex":"male","place":{"state":"ca"}}`

Comment: @NavinLeon What do you mean by inner keys? Can you explain more on why it would fail?

Comment: @Vega sorry I pasted the wrong code earlier, now I edited above. The key "state" is still in small letter.

Comment: @NavinLeon Please update your question with the updated key. The above answer is for a simple structure with {key : value} pair where value is a simple string.

Comment: @Vega I have updated the question, the "state" key is still in small letter if I follow your code. The code is not converting inner objects but outer objects are working perfectly fine.

Comment: @NavinLeon See my updated code which uses recursion to loop thru inner objects. Try and let me know.

Comment: Curious about the condition in the if() condition. Couldn't you just say if(typeof d === 'object') ?

Comment: Here is a version that looks in arrays and keeps them arrays. (@nnyby 's version turns them in objects) My version is for converting first letters of keys to lowercase as "MyKey" to "myKey". https://pastebin.com/G7feBj3C

Comment: what if i wanted to uppercase everything else too?

Answer (score 5):

You can't change a key directly on a given object, but if you want to make this change on the original object, you can save the new uppercase key and remove the old one:

```js
function changeKeysToUpper(obj) {
    var key, upKey;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            upKey = key.toUpperCase();
            if (upKey !== key) {
                obj[upKey] = obj[key];
                delete(obj[key]);
            }
            // recurse
            if (typeof obj[upKey] === "object") {
                changeKeysToUpper(obj[upKey]);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var test = {"name": "john", "Age": "21", "sex": "male", "place": {"state": "ca"}, "family": [{child: "bob"}, {child: "jack"}]};

console.log(changeKeysToUpper(test));
```

FYI, this function also protects again inadvertently modifying inherited enumerable properties or methods.

Comment: Added code to work recursively and added working snippet demo.